# Trying to sum the invested amount but keeps on saying non iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this code

```
def pv(PMT,i,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        fv=sum(PMT*(1+i)**n)
        return fv
```

It should add p+p(1+i)+p(1+i)**2, but I get

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

thanks for your help it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function takes an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) as argument, but your expression `PMT*(1+i)**n` resolves into an integer.

You can solve your problem by using a [generator-expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) instead:

```
def pv(PMT, i, n):
    fv = sum(PMT*(1+i)**n for j in range(0,n))

    return fv
```