# Python Investment Calculator

Tags: python, while-loop, calculator

Please I need help to figure out this. I don't know where I go off.
The Assignment is :
"Write a function investment(PMT, n, i) that calculates your customer's savings at some point in the future, if:

- an amount is invested at the END of every year, starting with amount
  of PMT at the end of this year,
- at an interest rate of i% per year, compounded annually,
- the investment amount doubles every second year (cumulatively)."

And there is my code:

```
def investment(PMT, n, i):
    x = 0

    while x < n:
        if x % 2 == 1:
            PMT = 2*(PMT*(1 + i)**n)
        else:
            PMT = PMT*(1 + i)**n

        x = x + 1

    investment_balance = PMT

    return round(investment_balance, 2)
```

The answer supposed to be: `investment(15000, 30, 0.1045) == 1954935238.47` but I am getting: 3.4728768295747016e+47.

Comment: Start with a small, simple test case.  Figure out the correct answer by hand, then compare the results from  your code.  Do not start by inputting huge values you think you know the answer for and then staring at the screen when it doesn't match.

Comment: Also, this lacks information about what PMT and n is.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what `PMT` is supposed to represent? That's where the problem is.

Comment: PMT is an amount invested at the END of every year.

Comment: @Hackares can you please write the proper formulae of each case . It would be good for me to create the logic & find the bug in the above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to sum the invested amount but keeps on saying non iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498245/trying-to-sum-the-invested-amount-but-keeps-on-saying-non-iterable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you're using looks like the one you'd use to calculate the [future value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value) of money with compound interest. That's on the right track, but you don't want to do that computation in a loop. Your results will be too large.

Try this instead.

- Set the initial investment balance to 0.
- Start looping over x number of years.
- If the year is odd (because we start counting at 0), double the payment.
- Apply the interest to the balance.
- Add the payment to the balance.

It's important to do that last step *last* because we're only adding the payment at the *end* of each year. That means interest shouldn't be applied in year 0. (More accurately, it will be applied to a 0 balance.)

If you do all that, you get a function that looks like this:

```
def investment(PMT, n, i):
    x = 0
    investment_balance = 0

    while x < n:
        if x % 2 == 1:
            PMT = 2* PMT
        investment_balance *= (1 + i)
        investment_balance += PMT
        x = x + 1

    return round(investment_balance, 2)
```

This works for the example input you gave.

Answer (score 0):

A couple observations:

Since the payment is made at the end of the year and interest is i% per year there should be no interest at the end of the first year.

If the investment doubles every second year you could calculate the effective interest rate over 2 years and then compound bi-annually (every second year). As in run this as a normal compound interest equation where PMT is doubled each compounding. Should make the logic a little easier. For odd n's you'd have to do a last compounding using the original rate.

Your equation is overwriting PMT on each loop. The PMT doesn't increase with interest, only doubled every second year. If PMT was $100 in year 0, it should only be $200 in year 2 instead of being compounded three times by your loop.